How can i use wix SDK to convert rich content to page elements?
I've got a next.js application and an API for rich content and I've to get rich content from API And I have to display them with the help of wix SDK in my next.js application. But there's a problem, I'm successful in getting rich content from API but I can't convert them into page elements with wix SDK and the wix articles confused me so I've no idea. can anyone help me???
there're a few articles in wix documents: https://dev.wix.com/docs/sdk | https://dev.wix.com/docs/go-headless/tutorials-templates/other-tutorials/working-with-rich-content | https://ricos.js.org/
I've seen a lof documents and I did everything the document said for example  :
npm i @wix/sdk
npm i @wix/blog
and I installed all of ricos.js plugins:
npm i ricos-viewer@9 classnames
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-code-block@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-audio@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-video@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-image@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-button@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-text-color@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-table@9
npm i add wix-rich-content-plugin-collapsible-list@9
npm i add wix-rich-content-plugin-divider@9
npm i add wix-rich-content-plugin-file-upload@9
npm i add wix-rich-content-plugin-giphy@9
npm i add wix-rich-content-plugin-hashtag@9
npm i add wix-rich-content-plugin-headings@9
npm i add wix-rich-content-plugin-html@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-link@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-link-preview@9
npm i  wix-rich-content-plugin-mentions@9
npm i  wix-rich-content-plugin-social-polls@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-spoiler@9
npm i wix-rich-content-plugin-vertical-embed@9
Also I've added all of files (RichContentViewer.tsx) that the document said but still It doesn't work because of this error:
./node_modules/@wix/image/dist/esm/Image.scss
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm
Location: node_modules\@wix\image\dist\esm\Image.js

RichContentViewer.tsx:
'use client'
import { RicosViewer } from 'ricos-viewer'
import { pluginVideo } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-video/viewer'
import { pluginAudio } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-audio/viewer'
import { pluginDivider } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-divider/viewer'
import { pluginHtml } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-html/viewer'
import { pluginLink } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-link/viewer'
import { pluginLinkPreview } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-link-preview/viewer'
import { pluginImage } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-image/viewer'
import { pluginTable } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-table/viewer'
import { pluginGallery } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-gallery/viewer'
import { pluginGiphy } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-giphy/viewer'
import { pluginActionButton } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-button/viewer'
import { pluginHashtag } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-hashtag/viewer'
import { pluginVerticalEmbed } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-vertical-embed/viewer'
import { pluginCodeBlock } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-code-block/viewer'
import { pluginMentions } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-mentions/viewer'
import { pluginFileUpload } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-file-upload/viewer'
import { pluginCollapsibleList } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-collapsible-list/viewer'
import { pluginPoll } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-social-polls/viewer'
import { pluginSpoiler } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-spoiler/viewer'
import { pluginHeadings } from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-headings/viewer'
import {
  pluginTextColor,
  pluginTextHighlight,
} from 'wix-rich-content-plugin-text-color/viewer'

const plugins = [
  pluginVideo(),
  pluginAudio(),
  pluginDivider(),
  pluginHtml(),
  pluginLink(),
  pluginLinkPreview(),
  pluginImage(),
  pluginTable(),
  pluginGallery(),
  pluginGiphy(),
  pluginActionButton(),
  pluginHashtag(),
  pluginVerticalEmbed(),
  pluginCodeBlock(),
  pluginMentions(),
  pluginFileUpload(),
  pluginCollapsibleList(),
  pluginPoll(),
  pluginTextColor(),
  pluginTextHighlight(),
  pluginSpoiler(),
  pluginHeadings(),
]

const RichContentViewer = ({ content }:any) => {
  return <RicosViewer content={content} plugins={plugins} />
}
export default RichContentViewer

can anyone explain the best way to use wix SDK.
